# Configuration Migration

Tags: configuration, migration

Keeping the configuration across multiple environments ( live / stage / dev ) is obviously very important, especially when you have multiple developers. Nobody likes the whole 'well it works on my machine' situation. In an attempt to avoid this issue we try to make sure that configuration changes that are required get done as a migration file.

I've found myself unsure on where exactly we should put these migrations. We tend to have a Client_Core module, which seems a fairly logical module to make the changes in, but are configuration changes a `data` migration (and as such sit in the 'data' directory) or should they be located in the `sql` directory? Is there actually a 'best practice' / 'Magento way' place for these migrations, or is it just a matter of it doesn't really matter, go with whatever you feel better?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using the `data` folder because when the scripts inside the `sql` folder are executed, not all configuration data is loaded.
To update a config setting run this code:

```
$path = 'some/path/here'; //path of the config
$config = Mage::getModel('core/config_data')->load($path, 'path');
$config->setValue('some value here')->setPath($path);
$config->save();
```

Or to set it for a specific store:

```
$path = 'some/path/here';
$config = Mage::getModel('core/config_data');
$config->setValue('some value here');
$config->setPath($path);
$config->setScope('stores');
$config->setScopeId(2); //store id here
$config->save();
```

But there is a catch. It doesn't work for all config settings. If the field has a backend model (see for example the base url or the number of lines for the customer street address) the backend model will be ignored (Learned that the hard way).

Comment: Interesting. Generally when I've programatically set the value I've used `Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::setConfigData`.

Comment: Double interesting :). I never knew you could do that. In this case I think you can disregard my answer and use it like that in the scripts from the `sql` folder. Since this way you use a core resource model you can be sure that the config section needed to run the scripts is loaded. But the issue with the 'backend_model' still remains. And I don't have a work-around for that.